# Store MatDatepicker Timestamp in MySQL

Tags: mysql, angular

I want to store the output of Angulars MatDatepicker in MySQL.
The issue is that the formats are not matching.
Here an example when the user picks 13.11.2020:

MatDatepicker returns the Date in the following format (with timezone):

```
2020-11-12T23:00:00.000000Z
```

MySQL use datetime as format. The raw value in the db is the same (but without timezone):

```
2020-11-12 23:00:00
```

This is the query which I use to insert the datetime:

```
INSERT INTO testtable (`datetime`) VALUES('2020-11-12T23:00:00.000000Z');
```

The issue is that on return to the frontend, the 12. of november is displayed.
I have a huge Formular with a lot of Datepicker. That's why I don't want to format the date by Angular.
Is there a solution how I can solve that by MySQL?

Comment: You are not adding from angular to mysql? you are posting to api right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Mat-Datepicker date format to DD/MM/YYYY in simplest way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55721254/how-to-change-mat-datepicker-date-format-to-dd-mm-yyyy-in-simplest-way)

Comment: Or if there no business issue you can store the date in the form of text.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try something like this:

```
insert into test_table_name (datetime_column) values (CAST(left('2020-11-12T23:00:00.000000Z',19) AS datetime));
```

Comment: By that, I store 12.11 23 o clock.